# PHP/JavaScript Email Contact Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Im trying to use a contact form for email which by default after submitting the mail redirects to another page. I would however like after the mail submits to stay on the same page but with a popup message telling the sender than the mail has been sent but without leaving the page. Below is the javascript from my HTML page & the PHP I'm trying to use.

Can anyone explain what I'm missing & how to do this please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#contactFormSubmit").click(function( event ) {
                $.post( “/contactengine.php", $("#contactForm").serialize() );
                $('#contactFormConfirmation').slideDown();
                $('#submitFormReset').click();
            });

        });
    </script>




<?php
$EmailFrom = "";
$EmailTo = "";
$Subject = "";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

Comment: You should use ajax if you want to stay on the same page.

Comment: @slim can you give an example of this please?

Comment: @markkane check my answer and let me know if you face any problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I think you should try this!

First run the php script as you would to send the email then after that include this line at the bottom of your php script

```
header("Location: http://myurl.com/contact?check=1");
```

Then on the contact page have an hidden input that contains the value 0 which is called check and then use url parameters to fill the input box.

On page load check the value of the hidden input box to see if its 1 or 0. If its 1 show a pop up box if its 0 load the page normally

I hope this helps!

**USE THIS CODE**

```
<form id="contactForm" method="post" action="contactengine.php">
    <div class="row half">
        <div class="6u">
            <input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Name" name="Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="6u">
            <input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Email" name="Email" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row half">
        <div class="12u">
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" name="Message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="contactFormConfirmation" style="display: none;">
         <div class="12u">
             <p style="color: white; background-color: #FF3B30;width: 325px;border-radius: 0.25em;padding: .3em;margin: 0 auto;">Thank you for getting in touch!</p>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="12u">
             <ul class="actions">
                  <li>
                      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="contactFormSubmit" class="form-button" value="Submit" />
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <input type="reset" name="reset" id="submitFormReset" class="form-button alt" value="Clear" />
                  </li>
             </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
  </form>
  <form name="checkf" id="checkf">
         <input name="check" id="check" value="0">
  </form>
```

**EDIT:**

Change the code you added just to the one below I forgot to add a line in lol

```
<script type="text/css">
  function fcheckf(){
    var x = document.getElementById('check').value;
    if(x == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
         alert("Thank you for submitting your data! - This is the pop up box content!");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Once you have added the above in, change your:

```
<body>
```

tag, to this:

```
<body onload="fcheckf()">
```

**Another Edit**

Now add this just before the

```
</body>
```

tag. This is important that it is pasted in the line before the body tag :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data=location.search;
if(data) {
data=location.search.substring(1);
data=data.split('&');
var pairs={};
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    var tmp=data[i].split('=');
    pairs[tmp[0]]=tmp[1];
    }
var f = document.checkf;
for (var i in pairs) {
    if(f.elements[i]) {f.elements[i].value = pairs[i];}
    }
}
```

**EDIT 56981 V3**

Use this code within your html

```
<script>
function fcheckf(){
var x = document.getElementById('check').value;
if(x == 0)
{
    return false;
}
else
{
     alert("Thank you for submitting your data! - This is the pop up box content!");
}
 }
</script>
<section id="fourth" class="contact">
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <span class="image-header-contact"><img src="images/contact-header.png" alt="Video" /></span>
            <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="content style4 featured">
        <div class="container small">
            <form id="contactForm" method="post" action="contactengine.php">
 <div class="row half">
    <div class="6u">
        <input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Name" name="Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="6u">
        <input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Email" name="Email" />
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row half">
    <div class="12u">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" name="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="contactFormConfirmation" style="display: none;">
     <div class="12u">
         <p style="color: white; background-color: #FF3B30;width: 325px;border-radius: 0.25em;padding: .3em;margin: 0 auto;">Thank you for getting in touch!</p>
      </div> 
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="12u">
         <ul class="actions">
              <li>
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="contactFormSubmit" class="form-button" value="Submit" />
              </li>
              <li>
                  <input type="reset" name="reset" id="submitFormReset" class="form-button alt" value="Clear" />
              </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
 </form>
 <form name="checkf" id="checkf">
     <input name="check" id="check" value="1">
 </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
   <script>
       var data=location.search;
 if(data) {
 data=location.search.substring(1);
 data=data.split('&');
 var pairs={};
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
var tmp=data[i].split('=');
pairs[tmp[0]]=tmp[1];
}
var f = document.checkf;
for (var i in pairs) {
if(f.elements[i]) {f.elements[i].value = pairs[i];}
}
}
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response - can you show me what this would look like as i can only get it now to reload the page of submission but no popup

Comment: Okay so on your page created a hidden in out with an Id of check and name of check with a value of 0

Comment: Im so sorry but as you can tell my knowledge is very limited - could you please show me this code? Thank you very much

Comment: No Problem at this into the bottom of your webpage: 
    <input type="hidden" id="check" name="check" value="0">

Comment: Ok ive pasted that into my HTML page ;-)

Comment: Okay great - I forgot to tell you that the input field needs to sit within a form so it should look like my edited answer. What you have just added in change with the new code within  my answer

Comment: Ok but where about? This this my html form code here...

http://jsfiddle.net/H8vvy/

Comment: I know though get this box with 0 in it...Have i done something wrong? See here: http://jsfiddle.net/4ewet/

Comment: Yep that is correct and no problem at all :) , give me an hour or so and ill get the next stage to you

Comment: Ok I've added your new script - Whats next? ;-)

Comment: Ok do i add that script before the <body> or at the end of my HTML page before the </body> ?

Comment: At the end before the </body> :)

Comment: after your url write ?check=1

Comment: For example: www.testwebsite.com/index.html?check=1

Comment: Ahhhhh! Wait Wait Wait - I just realised You need to end the script on the last edit you did. At the end of it add </script>

Comment: Im afraid its still not working. Have a look at my form HTML & the scripts from my HTML page -> http://jsfiddle.net/A7n2T/

Comment: Use the code I have just pasted at the bottom of my answer. And don't forget that your body tag must be <body onload="fcheckf();">

Comment: Ok we now have a popup (wooohoo) but 3 things: 1. Does it have to be a standard browser pop-up or can i make it a customised pop-up? 2. How do i stop the pop-up from popping up every time i refresh the page? 3. How do u remove this box with the 0 below the Submit/clear buttons? See here -> http://jsfiddle.net/U6gBw/

Comment: Nope you can now make it into any pop up you wish, where it says alert add your own code there. The pop up will only show when direct from the page with the url ending ?check=1 and add type="hidden" into the input tag :)

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your patience. Ok the input tag is now hidden (thank you) but now i have 2 major problems: 1. Still every time i visit the page the pop up pops up (even on refresh) - have i done something wrong? 2. Messages from the form sent fine to my email address but the message field is blank even though it was filled in before sending - any ideas?

Comment: Also would it be too much to ask for you to show me a fiddle example of how to style the popup? Id like to have a simple centred popup that overlays with a dark transparent background then fades away when clicked (like a modal) - is this possible?

Comment: No problem at all! Lets just hope my answer gets chosen and a vote up lol ;) - Anyways problem 1 is if you just visit your page without the ?check=1 at the end of the url it wont show :) and sure if you want to pop that in another question, and then ill be happy to answer, just pop a link in to that quesiton below and ill show you :)

Comment: Im sure it will as we are so close to fixing this & your help has been incredible. Im afraid though that even visiting the link without the ?check=1 in the url still triggers the popup - any ideas?

Comment: Woop Woop Lol!!- And its my fault lol remove value="1" from the input tag :) let me know if that works

Comment: Ok here is a link to the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417498/browser-alert-styling

Comment: Ive just answered the new question as well - Hope thats okay :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51843/discussion-between-km123-and-markkane)

Comment: What do you mean remove it? ;-)

Comment: Just so the input tag is like <input name="check" id="check" type="hidden">

Comment: Do you have a link to your page please?

Comment: Just posted in there my friend

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay on the same page you should use ajax. I would suggest to try the jquery `$.ajax` call as it seems to be easier.

Here is a simple example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "pathToThePHPGoesHere", // Here you have to place the path to the php file
    type: 'GET',
    data: $.extend({
        mailSubject: encodeURI(mailSubjectVar), // 1st variable name and value - you can place the content of your HTML box here
        mailBody: encodeURI(mailBodyVar) // 2nd variable name and value - you can place the content of your HTML box here
    }, tJS.getCommonPostData()),
    dataType: "json",  
    cache: false,
    success: function (responseText, status, xhr) {
       alert("Job done!"); // Here is what happens when the request is executed
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        tJS.manageError(jqXHR); // show an error message if something goes wrong
    }
});
```

You will need to `decode` the variables in your php script.

I'm not a php developer, but your code should look like:

```
$mailSubject = urldecode($_POST['mailSubject']);
$mailBody = urldecode($_POST['mailBody']);
```

In the `.$ajax` call I have encoded the characters, so you can transfer `UTF-8`, that is why you need to use `urldecode` in your php.

In order to use the above code, don't forget to include the [jquery](http://jquery.com/) library in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#contactFormSubmit").click(function( event ) {
            $.post("contactengine.php", $("#contactForm").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#contactFormConfirmation').html(data.message).slideDown();
            },'json');
        });
    });
</script>

<?php

//code to send email here...
$success = true;

$result['status'] = "ok";
$result['message'] = "Your email has been sent.";
if (!$success){
    $result['status'] = "error";
    $result['message'] = "Unable to send your message.";
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: In what way didn't it work? I created a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/scottfreeman/dC4Jb/ which might help (note the JSFiddle example doesn't work if you run it, because it doesn't do the PHP stuff).