# Browser Alert Styling

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I currently have a contact form that when completed triggers a browser alert/popup but i would like to style the popup to be more like a modal. So the popup would be centred & overlaid on the page with a dark transparent background that fades away when clicked - is this possible?

Here is my current script triggering the popup alert: http://jsfiddle.net/xf4C6/

```
function fcheckf(){
var x = document.getElementById('check').value;
if(x == 0)
{
    return false;
} 
else
{
     alert("Your message has been sent! Thank you for getting in touch.");
}
 }
```

Comment: Look at jQuery UI Dialog.  http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oki doki heres my answer:

**HTML**

```
<div id="popup" style="width:250px;height:250px;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);border:3px solid black;display:none;z-index:999;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;margin-left:-125px;margin-top:-125px;">
        <div style="width:230px;height:230px;margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;background-color:#FFFFFF;">
            Thank you for submitting your details<p>
            <div onclick="document.getElementById('popup').style.diplay='none';" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:75px;height:30px;background-color:#000000;cursor:hand;">
                Close
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

Change

```
alert("Your message has been sent! Thank you for getting in touch.");
```

to

```
document.getElementById("popup").style.display="block";
```

Comment: Ok the popup is now no longer a standard browser popup but how do i make it a modal style with a close button & dark transparent background?

Comment: To keep it simple I woulnt recommend allowing the user to move it, but just keep it static. To style it you would just use CSS and divs within that container.Please see my edit

Comment: So would this style be possible? http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/

Comment: It would yes! It would just a bit of styling.

Comment: Ok once i get to css i should be fine but in what way do i change this div code to then add my custom css?

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery ui dialog

[see documentation](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message)